# Powershell Pull Current OU

Tags: vb.net, powershell, active-directory

I need to be able to pull the current machine OU.  I found some VB code that could do this,but I would like to just be able to do in the script with out having to call VB.  Any ideas, the VB code is below.

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
DN = objSysInfo.ComputerName
WScript.Echo DN
```

-Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ADSystemInfo with this function.

```
function Get-LocalLogonInformation
{
    try
    {
        $ADSystemInfo = New-Object -ComObject ADSystemInfo
        $type = $ADSystemInfo.GetType()

        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            UserDistinguishedName = $type.InvokeMember('UserName','GetProperty',$null,$ADSystemInfo,$null)
            ComputerDistinguishedName = $type.InvokeMember('ComputerName','GetProperty',$null,$ADSystemInfo,$null)
            SiteName = $type.InvokeMember('SiteName','GetProperty',$null,$ADSystemInfo,$null)
            DomainShortName = $type.InvokeMember('DomainShortName','GetProperty',$null,$ADSystemInfo,$null)
            DomainDNSName = $type.InvokeMember('DomainDNSName','GetProperty',$null,$ADSystemInfo,$null)
            ForestDNSName = $type.InvokeMember('ForestDNSName','GetProperty',$null,$ADSystemInfo,$null)
            PDCRoleOwnerDistinguishedName = $type.InvokeMember('PDCRoleOwner','GetProperty',$null,$ADSystemInfo,$null)
            SchemaRoleOwnerDistinguishedName = $type.InvokeMember('SchemaRoleOwner','GetProperty',$null,$ADSystemInfo,$null)
            IsNativeModeDomain = $type.InvokeMember('IsNativeMode','GetProperty',$null,$ADSystemInfo,$null)
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,  but that does not seems to work.   Sorry maybe I am overlooking something, as I am new to PowerShell?

Comment: Never Mind, I had something closed that I needed :\  All seems well now THANK YOU! :)

Comment: Ok ran into another problem, I am trying to use the output in a switch statement based on OU.  However it does not seem to be working.

Comment: switch ($OU) { 
    "OU=RATES_TRADING"   { REACTOR_PUSH $RATES_Trading $REAC_VERSION }
    "OU=CRUDE_TRADING"   { REACTOR_PUSH $CRUDE_Trading $REAC_VERSION }
    "OU=GRAINS_TRADING"  { REACTOR_PUSH $GRAINS_Trading $REAC_VERSION }
    "OU=SPX_TRADING"     { REACTOR_PUSH $SPX_Trading $REAC_VERSION }
    "OU=Analytics"       { REACTOR_PUSH $Analytics $REAC_VERSION }
    "OU=RATES_ANALYTICS" { REACTOR_PUSH $RATES_Analytics $REAC_VERSION }
    
}

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ADSystemInfo` directly in Powershell (or at least it's not easy) according to this [page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730963.aspx)

> Well, OK, that’s not entirely true; it is possible to use ADSystemInfo from within PowerShell; however, the process is far from easy and even farther from being intuitive. That’s because ADSystemInfo is lacking a “wrapper” that makes it easy to access the object from a .NET language like Windows PowerShell. That results in a lot of gyrations involving .NET Reflection classes, the InvokeMember method, and, as near as we can tell, a lot of prayer.

But the page does provide examples for performing AD queries using the `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` .NET object. Here's an example from the page slightly modified to match your VB script:

```
$strName = $env:computername
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(Name=$strName))"

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter

$objPath = $objSearcher.FindOne()
$objPath.GetDirectoryEntry().distinguishedname
```